# Lost permalink editing bar and weird URL appears

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I tried to understand why I have the possibility to edit the permalinks from my posts but no from my category pages like "services". I explain this better using screen images, please check them out, thanks.

[No permalink editing bar and weird URL appears](http://www.arsmodea.com/img/no_permalink_editing.jpg)

[Posts are ok](http://www.arsmodea.com/img/permalink_edit_ok.jpg)

Comment: It would help if you post the code for your custom post type. I would think this issue is with that code.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but if you tell me in what file that code might be I'll paste it here. Is it on "posttype" file ? there is a "service.php", that is what you mean ?

Comment: What is creating the Services post type?

Comment: Thanks Joe for answer so fast. Sorry, what do you mean with that question, you are asking me where is the service poste type created ?

Comment: On the left side, the area that says Services is not part of the default Wordpress. Either it's getting created by a plugin or in your functions.php. That is what I am asking about because it looks like whatever is creating the services post type is missing something.

Comment: If you see below "Appearance" is a "Nictitate", it's just a theme. The theme come with a pre-design groups for the site, "services", "portafolio" and "clients", when you use different theme widgets, they will show information related to the data in those categories, like in this case, when I try to see the "web-design" page, as this page is part of the group of "services" it shows very similar, but I don't understand why the permalink bar is gone there, I was trying to understand where is created.